# $X-Y\sim$ Difference of random variables?

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim Ga(n,\lambda)$ and $Y\sim Ga(1,\lambda)$

Will $X-Y\sim Ga(n-1,\lambda)$?

I've tried creating a function $g(Y,X)=(Y-X,X)=(W,T)$ and then change the coordinates and integrate the density of $(W,T)$ with respect to T. However, I'm stuck at the integration. 
So, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:$ f_{(w,t)}=\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{\Gamma(n)}(w+t)^{n-1}e^{-(w+2t)\lambda}$

2nd EDIT, in response to Stelios comment: What if $X_1,...,X_n$ iid $Ga(1,\lambda)$, then would $\sum X_i - nX_{(1)} \sim Ga(n-1,\lambda)$ ? Now, the difference cannot take negative values. $X_{(1)}$ is the 1st order statistic. This edit has been transformed into this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885839/difference-of-random-variables) .

Comment: Could you spell out the integration that you are stuck with?

Comment: Also your title and content does not match.

Comment: @Memming Thanks for your interest in this question. I've edited the title and added the density.

Comment: Since the difference $X-Y$ can take negative values, it cannot be distributed as Gamma

Comment: @Stelios I've edited again. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Stelios, Should I create a new question with the 2nd edit in mind?