# Difference of random variables

Tags: probability

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ iid $Ga(1,\lambda)$, then would $\sum X_i - nX_{(1)} \sim Ga(n-1,\lambda)$ ?

$X_{(1)}=\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: This is an edit of a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885792/x-y-sim-difference-of-random-variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This time the answer is yes.

This is because $Ga(1, \lambda)$ is actually the exponential variable with parameter $\lambda$, which have the property of "forgetting the past". This is to say that, for any $y$, the distribution of $X_i -y $ knowing $X_i \geq y$ is still $Ga(1,\lambda)$.

Since this is true for any fixed $y$, we can say that the distribution of $X_i - Y$ knowing $X_i \geq Y$ is $Ga(1, \lambda)$ for any random variable $Y$.

Thus in the sum $\sum (X_i - X_{(1)})$, you have $(n-1)$ independent $Ga(1, \lambda)$ and one $0$. And we know that the sum of $(n-1)$ independent $Ga(1,\lambda)$ is $Ga(n-1,\lambda)$.

Indeed, this is not a rigorous proof. It only explains why the conclusion should be true.

Added:

Firstly remark almost surely all $X_i$ take distinct values

\begin{align}
E(f(\sum (X_i - X_{(1)}))) &= \sum_{j=1}^n E(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{(1)})) | X_{(1)} = X_j)P(X_{(1)} = X_j)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nE(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{(1)})) | X_{(1)} = X_j)
\end{align}

For a fixed $j_0$
\begin{align}
&E(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{(1)})) | X_{(1)} = X_{j_0}) \\
=& E(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{j_0})) | X_i \geq X_{j_0}, \forall i \neq j_0)\\
=&\int_0^{+\infty}E(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - y)) | X_{j_0}=y, X_i \geq y, \forall i \neq j_0) P(X_{j_0}=dy) \\
= & \int_0^{+\infty}E(f(\sum_{i\neq j_0}X_i - y) | X_i \geq y)P(X_{j_0}=dy)\\
= & \int_0^{+\infty}E(f(Ga(n-1,\lambda))P(X_{j_0}=dy) \\
= & E(f(Ga(n-1,\lambda))\int_0^{+\infty}P(X_{j_0}=dy) \\
= & E(f(Ga(n-1,\lambda))
\end{align}

Thus 
\begin{align}
E(f(\sum (X_i - X_{(1)}))) &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nE(f(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - X_{(1)})) | X_{(1)} = X_j) \\
& = E(f(Ga(n-1,\lambda))
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for your interest.

Do you know if your intuition leads to a rigorous proof?

Comment: You may make a sum over the case $X_{(1)} = X_i$ for each i. And first make the proof for $X_{(1)} = y$ for a fixed y, then integrate with respect to $dy$

Comment: I'm not managing to do the proof. Could you help me? I can't seem to find the conditional distribution.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I added a bit more details

Comment: Thanks. ;) what do you mean by $E(f(\sum (X_i - X_{(1)})))$? The expected value of the density of the r.v $\sum (X_i - X_{(1)})$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. $f$ is a arbitrary bounded measurable function. Here I didn't deal with the explicit density, but showed that applied to any $f$, $\sum (X_i - X_{(1)})$ and $Ga(n-1, \lambda)$ have the same expectation, so they should have the same probability distribution.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. What I know about measure theory is almost nothing. Thanks anyway. ;)